# Is there a biography of Robert Risch?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

The [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for computing symbolic integrals was developed by Robert Risch in the 1968-70 time frame.

Based on the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Risch), I know that Risch was awarded a Ph.D. by U.C. Berkeley in 1968, worked for IBM at their T.J. Watson research center at about that time, and was a member of the Institute for Advanced Studies from 1970-1972.

After that, nothing.  [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/2015301959_Robert_H_Risch) lists only two papers that he authored, the most recent in 1970.

Does anybody have any further information about Robert Risch?

Comment: The latest paper of his listed on MathSciNet is Algebraic properties of the elementary functions of analysis, Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979), no. 4, 743–759.

Comment: @Conifold, thank you, I was unaware of that paper, though I've heard of that theorem.  I notice that it was received in 1975, but not published until 1979.

Comment: A 'Bob Risch' is listed as a former permanent member of the IBM Mathematics of AI group (https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_group.php?id=9860). Also listed as being there in the late 70s in https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5545679, and on a 1998 patent (https://patents.google.com/patent/US6603573B1/en?inventor=Risch&assignee=IBM). Looks like he worked at IBM on various things that weren't published.